# ProtocolException when using getInputStream() on URLConnection

Tags: java, android, xml, urlconnection

**Edit:** The thing causing the error was a typo in the `url` variable declaration. The code provided works, given correct input. See my answer for details.

**Original Question:** I'm working on an application that regularly sends a `GET` request to a certain web server.

I have tried and verified the `URL` and the query in the browser and I get the information in `XML` format as expected.

The `URL/query` looks like this:
`http://foo.bar.com:8080/bla/ha/get_stuff?param1=gargle&param2=blurp`

I'm trying to get the raw content to my device (Android tablet) and output it to the screen.

However, when calling `getInputStream()` on my `URLConnection` object, I get the following exception:

> java.net.ProtocolException: Unexpected status line: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1

Calling `connect()` on the same object causes no exception (however other methods, such as `getContent()`, do).

`getContentType()` returns `null`.

I'm using `AsyncTask` to collect and display the data (displaying works fine).

In the code is also an `Authenticator` part, but removing it has no change on the exception thrown, so I don't think it's the issue.

Is this because the data is in `XML` format?

If so, how else should I access it?

**Code**

```
class GetPositionTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String url = "http://foo.bar.com/8080/bla/ha/get_stuff";
        String charset = "UTF-8";
        String param1 = "gargle";
        String param2 = "blurp";
        try {
            String query = String.format("param1=%s&param2=%s",
                    URLEncoder.encode(param1, charset),
                    URLEncoder.encode(param2, charset));

            Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
                @Override
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication("userName", "passWord".toCharArray());
                }
            });

            URLConnection urlConnection = new URL(url + "?" + query).openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
            InputStream response = urlConnection.getInputStream(); //Commenting this out prevents exception

            return "Made it through!"; // Never reaches this
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Exception in GetPositionTask";
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(s);
    }
}
```

**Note:** This is similar to a couple of other questions, however I wasn't able to solve my problem reading those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause was a simple type in the `url` string, which was supposed to be

```
String url = "http://foo.bar.com:8080/bla/ha/get_stuff";
```

rather than

```
String url = "http://foo.bar.com/8080/bla/ha/get_stuff";
```

Fixing that typo made the whole thing work as a charm.

Interestingly though, when I circumvented the whole concatenation and formatting business by pasting the complete `URL/query` into the `URL`constructor as below, it still worked (even though the `URLEncoder#encode` calls did switch some `:`characters out in `param2`).

```
URLConnection urlConnection = new URL("http://foo.bar.com:8080/bla/ha/get_stuff?param1=gurgle&param2=blurp").openConnection();
```

(in my real case, the `param2` variable includes a MAC address, and the `:`'s were replaced with something of the type `%xx`)

Answer (score 0):

You're connecting to an SSH server, not an HTTP server.

The reason it doesn't happen on `connect()` is that `connect()` doesn't actually connect. The other methods you mention do, if necessary.

Comment: Funny that the server owner just specified "The above XMP is the response to a HTTP `GET` request to [link]". So I'm connecting to an SSH server through a HTTP request?

Comment: Of course I meant XML, not XMP. Anyway, if you could point me in the right direction here, I'd be very grateful